# How to uninstall couchDB in windows

Tags: couchdb

I am using couchDB version 1.6.1 but now I want move for latest version 2.0 and it is recommended that if I want to use latest version of couchDB then I need to uninstall the older version but I am not getting how to uninstall the older version and move to newer version. I have tried to search in google but dint get proper solutions for this. How can I move to newer version.

Anybody If know, please let us know how can we do it.

Comment: I found the solution.. thank you

Comment: Would be nice if you share the solution :)

Comment: its easy.. go to **control panel** -> **add or remove programs** -> select **Apache CouchDB** and Uninstall

Comment: I used a second machine to transfer the data via replication, then uninstalled 1.6.1, installed 2.0 and finally replicated the data back.

Comment: @Carlos Neither "CouchDB" nor "Apache CouchDB" appear in "add or remove programs" but there is a CouchDB directory taking up ~600MB of space, so I know something hasn't been uninstalled...

Comment: CouchDB's data remains when uninstalling. If you wish to delete the data, delete the CouchDB folder.

Answer (score 3):

In my case (version 1.6.1), the installer (.msi file), when started, would notice that the software is already installed, and would offer me to "repair" or "remove" it. Try that.